# Finding a tab within a page using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am a newbie to selenium and am trying to access the tab full score card tab on the folloing website.

http://www.espncricinfo.com/icc-womens-world-cup-2013/engine/current/match/594903.html.

My code in Java is :

```
driver.get("http://www.espncricinfo.com/icc-womens-world-cup-2013/engine/current/match/594903.html");

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='st_1']")).click();
```

However it does not seem to be able to find the tab. Can you please help.

Thanks

Comment: Wow.  Good question.  Something really unusual about that page.  Haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

The "tab" is in an `iframe`

Before you can do anything with an element in an `iframe`, you have to "activate" the frame with `driver.switchTo().frame("live_iframe")`